# Doubt in a property of the Fibonacci Series.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I came across this question in a book where they asked me to prove that there are exactly four terms such that $F_{F_n}= F_n$. Well, I think that this is false and that there are exactly three. I have  proof for my statement. Please tell me whether my proof is wrong, or the question is.

It can be clearly seen that $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$ and $F_5=5$.For all $n>5$, we know can prove that $F_n> n$ as $F_n= F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ where $F_{n-1}\geq n-1$ and $F_{n-2}>1$. Therefore their sum, $F_n>n$. Is this proof correct, or is there a fourth term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a fourth term

Yes : $$F_{F_2}=F_2$$

Comment: It's rather easy to miss that it's not true that $$F_{F_n}=F_n \Leftrightarrow F_n=n$$

Comment: oh yes, i din't think of it like that....thank you....

Comment: @MXYMXY....well $F_{F_n}=F_n⇔F_n=n$ is true...the thing it that if i take it as, $F_1=1$, there are two cases for which I can get that 1.